# Remove HTML output from DOM from a certain place to a certain place

Tags: jquery, dom-manipulation

Due to inability to modify the source I'm stuck on a situation. I'm able to insert some own HTML, so I can create a starting point. I've also got a somewhat certain element to define as end point.

I'm wondering if its possible to remove outputted HTML in a strpos way PHP offers, but now using jQuery. I've searched for it in the forums but I didn't find relevant questions.

Below a simplified example:

```
<my startpoint>
<div>
  ..
  .. non editable output
  ..
  <identifier>
  ..
  .. more output
</div>
```

I want to use jQuery to edit it to:

```
   ..
  .. more output
</div>
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I've used several `$(selector).each()`'s to process the DOM and remove all the unwanted output.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be simplified as:

- You have a container
- You have an element in that container where:

  - everything before that element should be removed
  - an element containing that element should be (partly) removed
  - the split element itself should be removed

This can be done recursive where you simplify the problem with subcontainers of the initial container, until you have removed all the elements from the DOM that you wanted to remove. `.contents()` returns an Object containing all Nodes (including TextNodes). `.each()` cycles through all the elements in such an Object. Returning `false` in there will stop this cycle early. `$.contains(...)` is true when the element in the second argument is in the element in the first argument.

```
var start = document.getElementById('start');
var splitpoint = document.getElementById('splitpoint');

function removeUntil( parent, split ) {
    $(parent).contents().each( function( index, elem ) {
        if( elem == split ) {
            parent.removeChild( elem );
            return false;
        } else if( $.contains( elem, split ) ) {
            removeUntil( elem, split );
            return false;
        } else {
            parent.removeChild( elem );
        }
    } );
}

removeUntil( start, splitpoint );
```